# Use react to store binary data to SQL Server

Tags: node.js, sql-server, reactjs

I'm working on a feature that allows the user to upload a pdf to a SQL Server database. The user clicks a button to open a file dialog and selects the pdf they want to upload. The SQL Server database takes a `varbinary(max)`.

I'm using base64 to encode the file, however I am getting an error saying

> RequestError: Implicit conversion from data type varchar to varbinary(max) is not allowed. Use the CONVERT function to run this query

Looks like I'm sending a string, not binary.

Here is the code I'm using:

**React.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './styles.css';
import base64 from 'base-64';

class SaveSDS extends Component {
    constructor() {
        super();
        this.state = { user: {} };
        this.chemNameField = React.createRef(); // create ref for first name field
    }

    state = {
        file: null
    }

    handleFile(e) {
        e.preventDefault();
        let file = e.target.files[0];
        this.setState({file: file});
      }

      handleUpload(e){
        e.preventDefault();
        const data = new FormData();
        let file = this.state.file;
        data.append('file', file)
        var r = new FileReader();
        fetch('http://localhost:5000/db', {
            method: 'POST',
            headers: { "Content-Type": "application/json" },
            mode: 'no-cors',
            body: JSON.stringify({
                chemName: this.chemNameField.current.value,
                chemPDF: base64.encode(data)
            })
        })
        .then((res) =>{
            console.log(res)
        });

      }

      render() {
        return (
            <div className="submitForm">          
                    <div style={{padding: "10px"}}>
                        <input className="fileButton" type="file" accept=".pdf" name="file" onChange={(e) => this.handleFile(e)} />
                    </div>
                    <input type="text" style={{width: "50%"}} placeholder="Enter chemical name"  ref={this.chemNameField} />
                    <br />
                    <button type="button" onClick={(e) => this.handleUpload(e)}>Upload</button>
            </div>
        );
      }
}

export default SaveSDS;
```

And here is what I'm using on the express side:

**Server.js**

```
const express = require('express');
const bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var sql = require("mssql");
const app = express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
app.use(express.json({
    type: ['application/json', 'text/plain']
  }));

var config = {
    user: 'user',
    password: 'pass',
    server: 'localhost', 
   database: 'Master' 
};

app.post('/db', function(req, res) {
    console.log(req.body)
    res.set('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', '*');
    let connection = new sql.ConnectionPool(config, function(err) {
        let request = new sql.Request(connection);
        request.query("insert into chemicals (chemName, chemPDF) values ('" + req.body.chemName + "', '" + req.body.chemPDF + "')");
    });
});

const port = process.env.PORT || 5000; //get the process port
app.listen(port, () => console.log(`Server running on port ${port}`));
```

Is it even possible to send binary to the backend from react, or would it be easier to convert to binary on the backend? Maybe my approach is totally wrong.

Basically I want the user to be able to upload a file, then allow other users to open and view that file. I've done this in C# by uploading binary to SQL Server, then decoding it so people can view it. Not sure if that translates to node/react.

Thanks!

Comment: You are sending a JSON with a base64 content, which is a string.

To send binary data look at the *FormData* and File APIs.

Comment: I don't know how you issue queries with actual parameters in ReactJS, but I'm sure there must be a way, and you should absolutely use that instead of concatenating strings. SQL injection ahoy! (It's also madly inefficient with large binary values, even if you didn't have the text conversion issue.)